# SendEmail function : error because of formulas in blank rows

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a `sendEmail` function which works almost perfectly with my Google Sheet.

The `getLastRow` function return all my blank rows because they have an hidden formula and I'd like to grab only filled rows.

Here is my code :

```js
var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL SENT';
  
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  // Fetch the range of cells 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1,numRows-1,20);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[7] + "," + row[9] + "," + row[13]; 
    var message = row[18]; 
    var emailSent = row[19]; 
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) { // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = 'Un nouvel adhérent vous a été affecté';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 20).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Already tried `var data = dataRange.getDisplayValues();` instead of `var data = dataRange.getValues();`without significant result.

Do you have any idea ?

Here is a sample of my sheet :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution:

Replace this:

```
var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
```

with:

```
var numRows = sheet.getRange("F1:F").getDisplayValues().filter(String).length;
```

The latter will filter out the cells of your sheet that are **empty** even if they contain a formula.

### References:

- [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just add an if statement inside a for loop and check if one of the cells is empty, and break the loop if so.

Your code would look something like this:

```js
var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL SENT';
  
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  // Fetch the range of cells 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1,numRows-1,20);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    if(row[6] === "") break; 
    var emailAddress = row[7] + "," + row[9] + "," + row[13]; 
    var message = row[18]; 
    var emailSent = row[19]; 
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) { // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = 'Un nouvel adhérent vous a été affecté';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 20).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```